# Invoking activity when SlidingDrawer is dragged

Tags: android, android-activity, slidingdrawer

I need to make an application with an `activity` consisting of a `GridView` and `SlidingDrawer`.

I have done that, but now my problem is that I need to bring an activity for half of the screen whenever the `SlidingDrawer` is dragged and the other half will be my previous `activity` and when I drag back the `SlidingDrawer` then the `Activity` should be closed.

Is this possible to handle both the activities in the screen without any conflict and if possible how should I design those activities?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an `Activity` in a `SlidingDrawer`. You can put a `View` in a `SlidingDrawer`.

Comment: No i have to invoke an `activity` whenever i drag the `drawer`.. Both should be visible at a time..

Comment: @Hussain: I repeat, you cannot put an `Activity` in a `SlidingDrawer`.

Comment: i dont want to put the `Activity` inside `SlidingDrawer`.. I need to call a half page `activity` when the `SlidingDrawer` is dragged..

Comment: @Hussain: There is no concept in Android of "call a half page `Activity`".

Answer (score 0):

1. The owner `Activity` of your `SlidingDrawer` should extends `ActivityGroup`.
2. Get the view of the target activity, add view to `SlidingDrawer`'s content. Code like below:

   ```
   private void initSlidingDrawerContent() {
       mTestContent.removeAllViews();
       //View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.act_test, null);
       View view = activityToView(this, new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class));
       mTestContent.addView(view); 
   }

   private View activityToView(ActivityGroup parent, Intent intent) {
       LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = parent.getLocalActivityManager();
       final Window w = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity("TagName", intent);
       final View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;
       if (wd != null) {
           wd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           wd.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
           ((ViewGroup) wd)
                   .setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
       }
       return wd;
   }
   ```
3. NOTE： **NEVER** `startActivity(pkg, YourTargetActivity)`! So that the user never goes to YourTargetActivity as a stand-alone `Activity`.